# ¿ Botón en la barra de arriba predeterminada?

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Estoy haciendo un Google Maps con las API de Google, y al fin me han salido pero tengo un problema y es que como no sé cómo poner el código que voy a poner a continuación a un Fragment , necesito poner la típica barra de arriba con un botón en la derecha para poder ir atrás.

**MapActivity.java**

`public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapid);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng Valencia = new LatLng(39.4561165, -0.3545661);
    LatLng Valencia1 = new LatLng(37.4561165, -0.3545661);


    // IT IS NECESSARY FOR map.setMyLocationEnabled(True)

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return  ;
    }

    // IT IS NECESSARY FOR map.setMyLocationEnabled(True)


    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Valencia, 5)); // ZOOM AL EMPEZAR EL GOOGLE MAP



    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.box24))
            .title("valencia")
            .snippet("valencia")
            .position(Valencia));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.box24))
            .title("valencia")
            .snippet("111111.")
            .position(Valencia1));
}
```

}

El caso es que no me aparece ninguna barra y en caso de que me apareciera, probé ya siguiendo otros consejos pero no me funcionaron, no es difícil la pregunta pero no soy capaz de ponerla.

EDITO:

He puesto esto:

`@Override`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.atras:

            startActivity(new Intent(MapActivity.this, MainActivity1.class));

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Además de cambiar Activity a ActionBarActivity y me sale, pero si quiero poner un texto, al lado del icono , eso cómo ? (el icono esta en la derecha)

Comment: agregar un toolbar ?

Comment: antes de postear una pregunta te sugiero que busques un poco, algunos aspectos base ya han sido tratados.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es llamar a setCustomView() y crear una vista personalizada donde puedes ponerle el texto que quieras.

Te daré un trozo de código de mi app para que le des un vistazo y puedas sacar una idea:

```
// Set the layout XML
setContentView(layout_id);

// Set the header type
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar != null){
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_menu_header);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    if(header_mode.equals(HeaderMode.BackButton)){
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

    }else if(header_mode.equals(HeaderMode.MenuButton)){


    }else if(header_mode.equals(HeaderMode.WithoutButton)){
        // actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

    }
} // else{ activity without header bar }
```

El layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo utilizar las funciones nativas de android para manejar el historial de navegación en ves de iniciar una instancia nueva simulando volver atrás ya que las animaciones para avanzar y volvber son distintas y el manejuo en memoria tambien, pero si de todas maneras lo quieres hacer a tu modo te recomiendo destruir la actividad al abrir una nueva para que esta no quede en memoria o cuando el usuario presione volver atras desde el boton de hardware no vuelva a abrir actividades muertas.

Comment: Cómo puedo estando en el Google Map usando la API de Google volver atras de forma nativa sin poner un botón y cargue otra actividad anterior? Si lo quisiera hacer así, nunca he hecho que no quede en memoria, cómo sería? Te refieres a un Destroy o algo parecido?

Comment: Respecto a tu código no me aclaro mucho T.T

Comment: Porque si quiero poner lo de actionBar.set... donde lo pongo, dentro de onOptions? vale no, en onCreate supongo, voy a ver si va, respecto a lo destruir y no en memoria lo hiciste alguna vez?

Comment: en la función onCreate de la actividad, todo lo que sea configuración de barras de navegación y menus nativos debes hacerlo en onCreate, no confundir con onStart ya que el framework cuando llama a onCreate lo hace en un thread con contexto de la UI del sistema y es el primer punto donde puedes configurar el esqueleto de la aplicación y luego comenzar a recibir las instrucciones del resto del layout y su capa de negocio.

Comment: Para iniciar actividad y eliminarse de la memoria a si mismo debes llamara estas dos funciones en el mismo orden: startActivity(...); finish();, si necesitas entregar un resultado de una actividad a otra puedes usar startActivityForResult() desde la actividad principal. De todas maneras el boton back nativo de la barra de navegacion lo hace todo automatico, no necesitas destrir nada. Dale un vistazo al manejo de la navegacion en android y los tiempos de vida de las actividades.

Comment: Vale, gracias einfo128, le he puesto  startActivity(new Intent(MapActivity.this, MainActivity1.class)); finish(); Y sí que funciona, así que supongo que da resultado, hay alguna forma visual de ver que se va de memoria o es imposible?

Comment: voy a ver como implementar boton nativo de android y si veo que es mucho jaleo lo dejo así como has dicho destruyendo que funciona :)

Comment: Facil, presiona el boton volver atras del emulador o del movil, verás que no se verá la actividad que has cerrado. Eso por lo general se usa despues de un login, de esa manera cuando el usuario termina de loguearse y vuelve hacia atras la app se cierra pero no te muestra la pantalla de logueo porque ya estas logueado, es parte del diseño del software, navegación y usabilidad, se ve cuando haces el wireframe junto con el diagrama de flujo.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias !!

Comment: Si te funciona recuerda marcarme como solución. Saludos.

Comment: Tu código no lo he usado, te pongo como +1 de todas formas, aún así, me gustaría preguntarte una cosa, he puesto el texto mediante manifest android:label y flecha atrás mediante un case y menuItem, pero si quiero poner un icono delante del texto ? Donde teóricamente estaría el boton de atras nativo de android, como?

Comment: es decir, en el actionBar quede: icono - texto - icono

Comment: Eso lo hace de manera automatica android, debes usar el menu nativo de opciones, cuando la pantalla es corta y no alcanzan los íconos aparecen tres puntos para desplegar el menu, cuando usas una tablet y los iconos alcanzan se ven todos.